# Why is default Dialogrc file making screen monochrome?

Tags: scripting, colors, dialog

I have a bash script where I have the following code:

```
if [ ! -f /home/tools/test.dialogrc ]
then
dialog --create-rc "/home/tools/test.dialogrc"
fi
```

Which successfully creates a test.dialogrc file with the default colours if it doesn't find an already existing file.

I then have the following which I believe is supposed to direct dialog to use the file as source for its colours etc.

```
export DIALOGRC=/home/tools/test.dialogrc
```

However I end up with a dialog that's grey and black instead of the usual blue etc. **Note**: I have not changed the contents of the dialogrc file in any way, it's just the default settings.

[image: example]

If I remove or rename the file I get the default colours again.

Any idea what is wrong here? I believe the terminal identifies as xterm if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration file is written out with [`use_colors=OFF`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-_use_colors), because the corresponding state variable is false and would not be set unless dialog runs normally.

(The same is true of [`use_shadow`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-_use_shadow)).  Those are set in [`init_dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog_lib.html#h3-init_dialog) (among other things, the function that calls `initscr` or `newterm`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Was certain I had tried that before but this time it worked. Guess I must've had the setting of the path to the file wrong or something.